# Getting result from boost spirit grammar (phoenix push_back causes a compile error)

Tags: boost-spirit

I have the following spirit grammar.  I am trying to create a vector of AST node in `struct myresult` using the standard `push_back(at_c<0>(qi::_val), qi::_1)` but am getting compile errors (see below).

```
typedef vector<ZLS::ASTNode*> vector_astnode_t;

struct myresult {
vector_astnode_t turtle_commands;
};

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT
(
 myresult,
 (vector_astnode_t, turtle_commands)
);  


namespace spirit = boost::spirit;
namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
namespace ascii = boost::spirit::ascii;
namespace phoenix = boost::phoenix;


struct debugprint {
    string _name;
    debugprint( string n ) : _name(n) {}

    void operator()(int const& i, qi::unused_type, qi::unused_type) const {
        cout << _name << std::endl;
    }
    void operator()(qi::unused_type, qi::unused_type, qi::unused_type) const {
        cout << _name << std::endl;
    }       

    // todo: more of these for each type

};


template <typename Iterator>
struct lsystem_parser :  qi::grammar<Iterator, myresult() > {
    lsystem_parser( ZLS::Context* ctx )
    :   lsystem_parser::base_type(start) 
    ,   _ctx( ctx )
    {
        using qi::char_;
        using qi::float_;
        using qi::eps;
        using qi::lit;
        using qi::_1;
        using qi::_val;
        using phoenix::ref;
        using phoenix::push_back;
        using phoenix::at_c;

        float_parameters = '(' >> (float_ >> *(',' >> float_)) >> ')';

        /// turtle grammar ///
        draw_forward = ( char_('F') [ _val = new ZLS::ASTDrawForward(_ctx,0)] )
                                    [debugprint("draw_forward")];

        move_forward = ( char_('f') [ _val = new ZLS::ASTMoveForward(_ctx,0)] )
                                    [debugprint("move_forward")];

        turn_left = ( char_('+')    [ _val = new ZLS::ASTTurnLeft(_ctx,0)] )
                                    [debugprint("turn_left")];

        turn_right = ( char_('-')   [ _val = new ZLS::ASTTurnRight(_ctx,0)] )
                                    [debugprint("turn_right")];

        push_state = ( char_('[')   [ _val = new ZLS::ASTPushState(_ctx)] )
                                    [debugprint("push_state")];

        pop_state = ( char_(']')    [ _val = new ZLS::ASTPopState(_ctx) ] )
                                    [debugprint("pop_state")];

        turtle_commands = (draw_forward 
                        | move_forward  
                        | turn_left     
                        | turn_right    
                        | push_state    
                        | pop_state);       

        // >>>> THIS IS WHAT IS CAUSING THE ERROR <<<<<
        start = *turtle_commands[ push_back(at_c<0>(qi::_val), qi::_1) ];
    }
    qi::rule< Iterator, myresult() > start;
    qi::rule< Iterator, vector<float> > float_parameters;

    qi::rule< Iterator, ZLS::ASTNode* > draw_forward;
    qi::rule< Iterator, ZLS::ASTNode* > move_forward;
    qi::rule< Iterator, ZLS::ASTNode* > turn_left;
    qi::rule< Iterator, ZLS::ASTNode* > turn_right;
    qi::rule< Iterator, ZLS::ASTNode* > push_state;
    qi::rule< Iterator, ZLS::ASTNode* > pop_state;
    qi::rule< Iterator, ZLS::ASTNode* > turtle_commands;

    ZLS::Context*   _ctx;

};
```

The following is the actual errors returned from XCode:

```
container.hpp:492: error: no matching function for call to 'std::vector<ZLS::ASTNode*,    std::allocator<ZLS::ASTNode*> >::push_back(const boost::fusion::unused_type&)'
stl_vector.h:600: note: candidates are: void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::push_back(const _Tp&) [with _Tp = ZLS::ASTNode*, _Alloc = std::allocator<ZLS::ASTNode*>]
container.hpp:492: error: return-statement with a value, in function returning 'void'
```

EDIT:  Following is a revised spirit grammar that compiles and works.  There are a few subtle changes to note including using the phoenix `new_` operator and adding the following semantic action to `turtle_commands = ... [_val = _1]`

```
template <typename Iterator>
struct lsystem_parser :  qi::grammar<Iterator, vector_astnode_t() > {
    lsystem_parser( ZLS::Context* ctx )
    :   lsystem_parser::base_type(start) 
    ,   _ctx( ctx )
    {
        using qi::char_;
        using qi::float_;
        using qi::eps;
        using qi::lit;
        using qi::_1;
        using qi::_val;
        using phoenix::ref;
        using phoenix::push_back;
        using phoenix::at_c;
        using phoenix::new_;

        float_parameters = '(' >> (float_ >> *(',' >> float_)) >> ')';

        /// turtle grammar ///
        draw_forward    = ( char_('F')  [ _val = new_<ZLS::ASTDrawForward>(_ctx, (ZLS::ASTNode*)0)] )
                                        [debugprint("draw_forward")];

        move_forward    = ( char_('f')  [ _val = new_<ZLS::ASTMoveForward>(_ctx, (ZLS::ASTNode*)0)] )
                                        [debugprint("move_forward")];

        turn_left       = ( char_('+')  [ _val = new_<ZLS::ASTTurnLeft>(_ctx, (ZLS::ASTNode*)0)] )
                                        [debugprint("turn_left")];

        turn_right      = ( char_('-')  [ _val = new_<ZLS::ASTTurnRight>(_ctx, (ZLS::ASTNode*)0)] )
                                        [debugprint("turn_right")];

        push_state      = ( char_('[')  [ _val = new_<ZLS::ASTPushState>(_ctx)] )
                                        [debugprint("push_state")];

        pop_state       = ( char_(']')  [ _val = new_<ZLS::ASTPopState>(_ctx) ] )
                                        [debugprint("pop_state")];

        turtle_commands = (draw_forward
                        | move_forward  
                        | turn_left     
                        | turn_right    
                        | push_state    
                        | pop_state)[_val = _1];        


        start = *turtle_commands >> qi::eps;
    }
    qi::rule< Iterator, vector_astnode_t() > start;
    qi::rule< Iterator, vector<float> > float_parameters;

    qi::rule< Iterator, ZLS::ASTNode*() > draw_forward;
    qi::rule< Iterator, ZLS::ASTNode*() > move_forward;
    qi::rule< Iterator, ZLS::ASTNode*() > turn_left;
    qi::rule< Iterator, ZLS::ASTNode*() > turn_right;
    qi::rule< Iterator, ZLS::ASTNode*() > push_state;
    qi::rule< Iterator, ZLS::ASTNode*() > pop_state;
    qi::rule< Iterator, ZLS::ASTNode*() > turtle_commands;

    ZLS::Context*   _ctx;

};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't directly use `operator new` inside of semantic actions, use [phoenix::new_<>](http://boost-spirit.com/dl_docs/phoenix-2/libs/spirit/phoenix/doc/html/phoenix/composite.html#phoenix.composite.object.new) instead.

Moreover, attributes for rules are specified using the function notation syntax. Therefore, you'll need to change your rule declarations to:

```
qi::rule< Iterator, ZLS::ASTNode*()> draw_forward;
```

Here is an additional tip. If you change the start rule to:

```
start = *turtle_commands >> qi::eps;
```

you can avoid the semantic action alltogether. By converting the rule into a (parser) sequence you can leverage the attribute propagation rules for sequences, allowing to directly map the first element of your fusion sequence (the `vector_astnode_t turtle_commands`) onto the first element of the parser sequence (the `*turtle_commands`).

I'm not able to compile your example as it is incomplete, so more problems might be hidden.